# Magento CE 1.8.1.0 grand total including tax is incorrect

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Hitting a brick wall here, for some reason Magento in the shopping cart is actually discounting the VAT from the total due. We are working with UK VAT (20%), and catalog prices include tax.

In this example the subtotal including tax comes to £9.50

So why on earth can the grand total including Tax come to £7.92? We haven't applied any discount to the item, so it's even more confusing. The grand total is worked out completely wrong for some reason.

Data displayed in cart:

```
Subtotal (inc VAT)  £9.50
Grand Total Excl. Tax   £6.34
Tax £1.58
Grand Total Incl. Tax   £7.92
```

Is this a confirmed bug in Magento CE 1.8.1.0 or is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this. we too are having this issue. we need to know whether its aMagento bug or some bug due to site upgrade and data transfer.For us this is happening once in a while.

Comment: I'd also like to know if you ever fixed this. We build stores in Magento all the time and have now come up against the exact same issue as your question. Not using any discounts and can confirm tax rates are all set up correctly. Bizarre.

Comment: me too it happened on magento 1.9.3.4 after works months issue occurs, it fixed by @sylvesters' code adding

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered the same issue, 
steps to solve it are:

1. Go to this location : app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
2. Make a copy of it in app/code/local : app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
3. next on line number 1221 add msrp

   > ```
   > <shipping>
   >    <class>sales/quote_address_total_shipping</class>
   >    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,msrp</after>
   >    <before>grand_total</before>
   > </shipping>
   > ```
4. Next add on line 1230 add

   > ```
   > <msrp>
   >    <class>sales/quote_address_total_msrp</class>
   >    <before>grand_total</before>
   > </msrp>
   > ```
   >
   > 5. this should solve your issue. Thank you :)

Comment: This solved my issue, Thanks a lot, and do you know reason for happen it becoz my site tax calculation was works fine before then occur this extract issue, after add your code it working fine now magento version 1.9.3.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some configuration issue with catalog price rules and tax class setting.

Just checked tax class is working fine adding tax in grand total, without any issue.

If you have setup promotion or discount for user type in that and might be same class with same user type is added from tax class setting might be due this, system provide discount to that user type and showing that tax is added.

Please recheck setting once and let me know if still we are facing same issue.

Email: phptesting37@gmail.com

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply - unfortunately still facing the same, no discounts are applied to the order, so I'm still confused. Any further suggestions please?

Comment: Ok, Please share what steps are you followed to added tax class because above provided solution was implemented. and it worked.