# Grant total subtracts tax in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

All the sudden our Magento stopped calculating grand totals correctly, without any known changes on our side. When tax rule applies, Magento correctly calculates

- product prices including tax
- subtotal including tax
- tax itself

But final price is too low. It excludes tax and this is what customer is asked to pay during checkout.
[image: Sample checkout]

Our tax settings in Magento.
[image: Tax settings in Magento]
[image: Tax settings in Magento][image: Tax settings in Magento]

I'm running out of ideas, what could be wrong and what caused it. Would you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by Przelewy24 extension. It didn't even have to be turned on. Once it was uploaded to the server, it caused the issue. After deleting it from the server everything came back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solution of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42826358/2787671

For me it was enough to copy `config->global->sales->totals->msrp` node of app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml into my app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/config.xml

and add:

```
<before>grand_total</before>
```

Result:

```
<sales>
  <quote>
    <totals>
      <msrp>
          <class>sales/quote_address_total_msrp</class>
          <before>grand_total</before>
      </msrp>
    </totals>
  </quote>
</sales>
```